# Constructing Extended User Principal without explicit Principal Context of domain

Tags: c#, directoryservices, account-management, principalcontext

Recently I've been implementing custom `ExtendedUserPrincipal` class similar to sample [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/04/11/querying-active-directory-using-principal-extensions-in-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement.aspx). The only problem for me is to construct new instance based on existing instance of base class (e.g. `UserPrincipal.Current`), to map existing user principal to my extended version. 
For now, I'm using explicit creation of domain context:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.name");
return ExtendedUserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,
     IdentityType.Sid, user.Sid.ToString());
```

What I'd like to do it to construct it without explicitly specifying domain context, e.g.

```
return Extended.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(SomeHelper.GetDomainContext(user), 
     user.Sid, user.Sid.ToString());
```

<s>`user.Context` is of no help here.</s>  Is this possible or prohibited by design (security concerns maybe)?

Comment: Assuming a .net framework version of 3.5 or higher: wouldn't `user.Context` suffice?

Comment: Yeah, `user.Context` is a working solution! Thank you. Initially I rejected it due to failure with one of the tests (constructed principal was not a member of some group - but that was bug in a test, `IsMemberOf` does not support nested groups), but now it is OK!. Can you post this as an answer for me to accept?